# How to search within videos of a single user with YouTube API?

Tags: web-services, youtube, youtube-api

I am building a music video streaming website with the YouTube API, whereby I will upload all my videos by my account and get my own videos with the user-specific feed.

I would like to know if it's possible and how to search within videos uploaded by a user, i.e. the search should return results containing only videos I uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using v1/v2 of the YouTube Data API, the relevant parameter to add to your search query is `author=USER`, where *USER* is either a YouTube username or a YouTube channel id.

This is documented at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#authorsp